# Adobe Livecycle (XFA) forms generated by iTextSharp render differently in Acrobat and Reader

Tags: forms, pdf, itext, livecycle, xfa

EDIT: Link to test files below.

As part of a project, I have created dynamic PDF forms in LiveCycle Designer 11.0. These forms are set to be reader enabled in Acrobat before being forwarded to the developer. He then populates the PDF using iTextSharp 5.5.6.

This form has many dynamic properties including hidden fields, dynamic subforms, etc.

When the generated form is opened in Adobe Reader 11.0.12 (my version, but others are affected), the form is a) read only and b) does not show all of the dynamic fields even though the criteria has been satisfied to display them and they have been filled with data. Some are shown.

When it is opened in Adobe Acrobat 11.0.9, the form renders as expected. Sections & fields are displayed/hidden as the form's logic dictates. The form is also fillable, it is not read only or flattened.

When I compare the Security settings of the forms in Acrobat, vs Reader, the "Filling of form fields" setting in Acrobat is set to "Allowed", while it is set to "Not Allowed" in Reader's Security settings.

Here is a link to a zip containing the following:
1) A dynamic PDF generated in iTextSharp
2) An auto-generated class file for the form
3) The data mapping Program.cs file

[Link to Test file showcasing the issue](https://onedrive.live.com/?id=F35E15F1F3E4F926%21107&cid=F35E15F1F3E4F926&group=0&parId=root&authkey=%21AIaCiR2ew0Du9%5Fc&action=locate)

When the file is opened in Acrobat, it works as expected. When it is opened in Reader, it becomes read only and both SignatureA and SignatureB are displayed, when only one should be shown based on which radiobutton is selected in the Signature Test section.

I do not have access to the codebase, so I cannot test the application on my end. Is there any setting in iTextSharp that may be causing this problem?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: You should at least provide one sample file.

Comment: Hi yms,

Will do. Just need to get one generated.

Comment: Finally got a test case generated: https://onedrive.live.com/?id=F35E15F1F3E4F926%21107&cid=F35E15F1F3E4F926&group=0&parId=root&authkey=%21AIaCiR2ew0Du9%5Fc&action=locate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PDF is not updated by an incremental update, which destroys the "reader enabled" feature (the digital signature becomes invalid due to a full rewrite).

You shall create the PdfStamper instance in append mode:

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper stamper = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper(reader, ms, '\0', true);
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the help! I will send this on to the dev. and hopefully it will do the trick. I came across that solution before but dismissed it as we weren't getting the "This document enabled extended features" error in Reader. I tested it on Adobe DC on an non-admin PC and got that error. If only I had gotten it earlier.

Comment: This indeed is the solution. Thanks Setasign!